# How to patch File and CoreExtensions for Timecop

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

I need to monkey-patch File. Timecop doesn't affect the time that the file system reports, which is what `File.atime` uses and in turn that's what HttpClient uses when posting a file to a server, which in turn means VCR doesn't quite work as desired. AFAIK, this means I can't use refinements.

I don't understand what's going on here:

```
class File
  def atime
    "this one happens"
  end
end

module CoreExtensions
  module File
    module TimecopCompat
      def atime
        "this one does not"
      end
    end
  end
end

File.include CoreExtensions::File::TimecopCompat

File.new('somefile').atime # --> "this one happens"
```

Why does the module-based monkey patching not happen? What do I need to change for it to work? Is there a different kind of monkey-patching that I should be using?

Comment: Not strictly related to your question, but be aware that using Timecop is [no longer recommended](https://andycroll.com/ruby/replace-timecop-with-rails-time-helpers-in-rspec/). It's pretty well accepted that it's better to use Rails TimeHelpers nowadays, especially since Timecop hasn't been updated in over a year. At time of writing, it doesn't formally support the latest ruby. (At least it's not tested in the repo's travis.yml) Of course, if you are maintaining an older app that just hasn't had time to upgrade, then that's a good enough reason to continue using it. Just be aware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is related to the way `include` appends the module to the ancestor chain. "[Ruby modules: Include vs Prepend vs Extend](https://medium.com/@leo_hetsch/ruby-modules-include-vs-prepend-vs-extend-f09837a5b073)" provides a very detailed overview of the differences between `include` and `prepend`.

Take a look at these two examples:

```
class Foo
  def hello
    "1"
  end
end

module Bar
  def hello
    "2"
  end
end

Foo.include Bar

Foo.new.hello
# => "1"
Foo.ancestors
# => [Foo, Bar, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

versus

```
class Foo
  def hello
    "1"
  end
end

module Bar
  def hello
    "2"
  end
end

Foo.prepend Bar

Foo.new.hello
# => "2"
Foo.ancestors
# => [Bar, Foo, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Basically, you want to use `prepend` in your case as `include` won't override the existing method.

Comment: Ah, neat, I see: `File.include` would mean that if the function isn't already defined in `File`, it's looked for in the included module. `Prepend` would mean that if the function isn't defined in the prepended module, then it's looked for in `File` (and so up on the chain). Neat!

Answer (score 1):

`include` is not some magic thing. It is very simple actually: it makes the module the superclass of the class it is mixed into. Now: do superclass methods override subclass methods? No, of course not, it is the other way around.

Therefore, `include` cannot possibly override methods of the class the module is being `included` into.

That is what `prepend` is for, which mixes in a module at the *beginning* of the ancestors hierarchy. (Which unfortunately cannot be simply explained using inheritance, it is something different.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify your example without changing the question.

```
module TimecopCompat
  def atime
    "this one does not"
  end
end
```

I have left the class `File` alone as it already has an instance method [File#atime](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/File.html#method-i-atime).

```
File.new('temp').atime
  #=> 2019-07-16 20:20:51 -0700
```

As explained by the other answers, executing

```
File.include TimecopCompat
```

results in:

```
File.ancestors
  #=> [File, TimecopCompat, IO, File::Constants, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject] 
File.new('temp').atime
  #=> 2019-07-16 20:20:51 -0700
```

whereas executing

```
File.prepend TimecopCompat
```

results in:

```
File.ancestors
  #=> [TimecopCompat, File, IO, File::Constants, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject] 
File.new('temp').atime
  #=> "this one does not"
```

It is poor practice, however, to change the behavior of any core method, as its original behavior may be relied upon elsewhere in the program.

Here there are two acceptable practices. The first is to create a method (`new_atime`, say) that has a `File` object (`file`, say) as its argument:

```
file = File.new('temp')
x = new_atime(file)
```

`new_atime` cannot be chained with a `File` object as its receiver, but that is a small price to pay for a safe and robust solution.

The second option is to use [Refinements](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) to `refine` the `File` class.

```
module RefinedFile
  refine File do
    def atime
      "this one does not"
    end
  end
end

class C
  using RefinedFile
  File.new('temp').atime
end
  #=> "this one does not"
```

We can confirm that `File#atime` has not been altered outside the class `C`:

```
File.new('temp').atime
  #=> 2019-07-16 20:20:51 -0700
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the actual call to `file.atime` is within the `httpclient` gem, which in turn is wrapped both by the API gem (in this case, Boxr) *and* VCR. AFAIK, neither of these of these approaches would work in this case.